# Email id and phone number not validating

Tags: android, validation

Hi In My application checking validation for email id and phone number but it's not validating both and simply it's saving into database.
I want to check the email id and phone number if it's both correct i want to do next process
Can any one please help me

**ContactUs.java**

```
public class ContactUs extends Activity 
{
    EditText fname1,lname1,mobile1,altmob1,email1,comment1;
    String data="";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contactus);        
        fname1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);

        lname1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        mobile1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile);
        altmob1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.altno);
        email1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        comment1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.coment);

        Button Send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Send); 

        Send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {             
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                 String fname = fname1.getText().toString();
                 String lname = lname1.getText().toString(); 
                 String mobile = mobile1.getText().toString();
                 String altmob = altmob1.getText().toString(); 
                 String email = email1.getText().toString();
                 String comment = comment1.getText().toString(); 

                if(fname.equals(""))
                {           
                    fname1.setError( "Please Enter First Name" );
                }
                else if(lname.equals(""))
                {           
                    lname1.setError( "Please Enter Last Name" );
                }               
                else if(mobile.equals(""))
                {           
                    mobile1.setError( "Please Enter Mobile No." );
                    isValidMobile(mobile);
                }
                else if(altmob.equals(""))
                {           
                    altmob1.setError( "Please Enter Altenative Mobile No." );
                }
                else if(email.equals(""))
                {           
                    email1.setError( "Please Enter EmailId" );
                    isValidMail(email);

                }
                else if(comment.equals(""))
                {           
                    comment1.setError( "Please Enter Your Comments here" );
                }
                else
                {

                    try{

                        String queryString ="fname="+ fname
                                 +"&lname="+lname+"&mobile="+mobile+ "&altmob="+altmob+"&email="+email+"&comment="+comment;
                    data = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("Contactform",queryString);
                    fname1.setText("");
                    lname1.setText("");
                     mobile1.setText("");
                     altmob1.setText("");
                     email1.setText("");
                     comment1.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(
                            ContactUs.this,
                            "Message:Records Saved Sucessfully",

                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                     catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                }   
            }           
        });
    }
    private boolean isValidMail(String email) 
    {
        boolean check;
        Pattern p;
        Matcher m;

        String EMAIL_STRING = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

        p = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_STRING);

        m = p.matcher(email);
        check = m.matches();

        if(!check)
        {
            email1.setError("Not Valid Email");
        }
        return check;
    }
    private boolean isValidMobile(String mobile) 
    {
        boolean check;
        if(mobile.length() < 6 || mobile.length() > 13)
        {
            check = false;
            mobile1.setError("Not Valid Number");
        }
        else
        {
            check = true;
        }
        return check;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are edittext box with property email

android:inputType="textEmailAddress"

in your code

```
 else if(mobile.equals(""))
                {           
                    mobile1.setError( "Please Enter Mobile No." );
                    isValidMobile(mobile);
                }
```

it check if email in blank then go to isValidMobile

so use

```
 else if(mobile.equals(""))
                {           
                    mobile1.setError( "Please Enter Mobile No." );

                }
else if(!isValidMobile(mobile)){
 // do somting
}
```

and similar for email

Answer (score 0):

Try this for checking email:

```
public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    if (target == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
    }
}
```

For telephone number check:

```
public final static boolean isValidPhone(CharSequence target) {
    if (target == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return android.util.Patterns.PHONE.matcher(target).matches();
    }
}
```

And please update your code with as :

```
    public class ContactUs extends Activity {
    EditText fname1, lname1, mobile1, altmob1, email1, comment1;
    String data = "";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contactus);
        fname1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);

        lname1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        mobile1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile);
        altmob1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.altno);
        email1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        comment1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.coment);

        Button Send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Send);

        Send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String fname = fname1.getText().toString().trim();
                String lname = lname1.getText().toString().trim();
                String mobile = mobile1.getText().toString().trim();
                String altmob = altmob1.getText().toString().trim();
                String email = email1.getText().toString().trim();
                String comment = comment1.getText().toString().trim();

                if (fname.length() != 0) {
                    if (lname.length() != 0) {
                        if (mobile.length() != 0 && isValidMobile(mobile)) {
                            if (altmob.length() != 0 && isValidMobile(altmob)) {
                                if (email.length() != 0 && isValidMail(email)) {
                                    if (comment.length() != 0) {

                                        try {

                                            String queryString = "fname="
                                                    + fname + "&lname=" + lname
                                                    + "&mobile=" + mobile
                                                    + "&altmob=" + altmob
                                                    + "&email=" + email
                                                    + "&comment=" + comment;
                                            data = DatabaseUtility
                                                    .executeQueryPhp(
                                                            "Contactform",
                                                            queryString);
                                            fname1.setText("");
                                            lname1.setText("");
                                            mobile1.setText("");
                                            altmob1.setText("");
                                            email1.setText("");
                                            comment1.setText("");
                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    ContactUs.this,
                                                    "Message:Records Saved Sucessfully",

                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        comment1.setError("Please Enter Your Comments here");
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    email1.setError("Please Enter Valid EmailId");
                                }
                            } else {
                                altmob1.setError("Please Enter Altenative Mobile No.");
                            }
                        } else {
                            mobile1.setError("Please Enter valid Mobile No.");
                        }
                    } else {
                        lname1.setError("Please Enter Last Name");
                    }

                } else {
                    fname1.setError("Please Enter First Name");
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private boolean isValidMail(String email) {
        boolean check;
        Pattern p;
        Matcher m;

        String EMAIL_STRING = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

        p = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_STRING);

        m = p.matcher(email);
        check = m.matches();

        if (!check) {
            email1.setError("Not Valid Email");
        }
        return check;
    }

    private boolean isValidMobile(String mobile) {
        boolean check;
        if (mobile.length() < 6 || mobile.length() > 13) {
            check = false;
            mobile1.setError("Not Valid Number");
        } else {
            check = true;
        }
        return check;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running your valid email check but ignoring the result. As long as you enter some text the call to save will work.

If you incorporate the return values from your is valid check methods, you can stop saving when those calls return false.

e.g.

```
 if(mobile.equals(""))
 {           
     mobile1.setError( "Please Enter Mobile No." );
 }
 else if(!isValidMobile(mobile))
 {           
     mobile1.setError("Not Valid Number");                   
 }
```